# QueryDict Object has no attribute session Django

Tags: python, django, session, python-requests

So I basically have a login form which I have defined like this:

```py
def login_request(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST
        auth_backend = AuthenticationBackend()
        login_form = LoginForm(data)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            user = auth_backend.authenticate(data, password=data['password'], email=data['email'])
            if user:
                login(data, user)
                # redirect to homepage
            else:
                login_form.add_error('password', "Password doesn't match email")
    else:
        data = {}
        login_form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': login_form, 'data': data})
```

If the given conditions match, the user must be logged in. However, when I do

```py
login(data, user)
```

I get this error:

```py
Internal Server Error: /users/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Iyappan\PycharmProjects\pyDjangoTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Iyappan\PycharmProjects\pyDjangoTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Iyappan\PycharmProjects\pyDjangoTest\users\views.py", line 34, in login_request
    login(data, user)
  File "C:\Users\Iyappan\PycharmProjects\pyDjangoTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 99, in login
    if SESSION_KEY in request.session:
AttributeError: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'session'
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix this? Please help me, thanks in advance!
Middleware:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: show us your settings MIDDLEWARE part

Comment: @iklinac I posted the middleware info. Please look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing this:

```
if user:
    login(data, user)
```

make it:

```
if user:
    login(request, user)
```

Comment: Change the: user = auth_backend.authenticate(data, password=data['password'], email=data['email'])...... to...... user = authenticate(password=data['password'], email=data['email']).... Also don't forget to use request in if statement with this

Comment: its because data is the request.POST object whereas I needed to pass in the request object only

Comment: That is what i said in the very first step.